# SEO - Rich snippets why i see the price in the Test tool but not in the google results

Tags: seo

Recently i learned about http://schema.org and i implemented it to my site.

I have several questions:

1. Why i see the price tag in the rich snippets test tool but not in the google results. Take a look at the result: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dilti.net%2FLadys-Joy-with-rose-oil-nourishing-cream-50-ml-Ladys-Joy-generously-hydrates-the-skin-product-rose-oil-with-the-lowest-price-generously-hydrates-the-skin-a-special-gift
2. How i can add the rating stars to the results ? Right now at the test tool i see only the price, but can i add there also the rating stars ?
3. Is there any way to display a product image in the results ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: These are three *separate* questions, so you should focus only on one of these questions here and open new questions for the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

Answers for your question in the order they were asked.

1. Some times Google take time to crawl your schema implementation and display the data. When i implemented it one of the site, it took like approx 30 days.

2.You need to implement schema.org/product to show the star ratings. Details can be obtained here. http://schema.org/Product

3. I doubt there is support to show images in SERPs.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Minion on answer #1 and #2 and for the answer for question #3, here you go:

Showing image in SERP through rich snippet is only possible for recipe rich snippet.

For eCommerce sites, you can have **Google merchant account** and thus you will be able to bring product images in rich snippet in SERP.

There is already similar question and its answers here on Stackoverflow, head onto: [How can I get a product image in a rich snippet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147184/how-can-i-get-a-product-image-in-a-rich-snippet)